# Use the tab bar html/css/js from Material Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I'm trying to use get this tab bar from Material Components: https://material.io/develop/web/components/tabs/tab-bar/

I'm having trouble following the installation steps. This is what I have so far:

tab.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tab.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
        <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
          <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
            <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">favorite</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Favorites</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Favorites2</span>
                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Favorites3</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

tab.css:

```css
<style lang="scss"> 

@import "@material/tab-bar/mdc-tab-bar";
@import "@material/tab-scroller/mdc-tab-scroller";
@import "@material/tab-indicator/mdc-tab-indicator";
@import "@material/tab/mdc-tab";
body{ 
  background-color: blue; 
}
#app 
{ 
main 
{ 
margin-top:65px; 
} 
div.mdc-layout-app--main-container{ display: block !important;} 
div.mdc-layout-app 
{ 
max-width: 1000px; 
background-color: white !important; 
margin: 0 auto; 
} 
header.mdc-top-app-bar 
{ 
max-width: 1000px; 
} 
} 
</style>
```

```js
import {MDCTabBar} from '@material/tab-bar';

const tabBar = new MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('.mdc-tab-bar'));
```

I want it to look like the demo, but right now it looks like something completely different. I was wondering if someone could break down these steps more for me as I'm extremely confused. Thanks. All help is appreciated.

This is what it looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dtMm.png)

I wanted it to look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlecl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run SCSS in the browser? If so, this is the problem. The "CSS" portion of your code is actually SCSS, a nested syntax that needs to be compiled down to regular CSS in order for the browser to be able to read it. For example:

**SCSS (Browser cannot read)**

```
#app { 
  main { 
    margin-top: 65px; 
  }
}
```

**CSS (Works fine)**

```
#app main { 
  margin-top: 65px; 
}
```

Material should provide plain CSS version for you, otherwise you will need to use a compiler.

Comment: Thank you, but that still doesn't fix it. It still looks the same. In my edits I posted what I want it to look like and what it currently looks like

Comment: `tab.css` is still trying to use the nested SCSS syntax

Answer (score 0):

To add on Simran his answer:

I see no `<script src="app.js"></script>` in your HTML.

You need to compile the code below using babel and include the output file in your HTML.

```
import {MDCTabBar} from '@material/tab-bar';

const tabBar = new MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('.mdc-tab-bar'));
```

---

If it is unclear how you do this re-read the [Getting started](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/)

Step 3: Webpack with ES2015 is about compiling JavaScript using Babel